# How do Python Generators Save Memory

Tags: python, generator

I understand the general idea that a generator returns an iterable that 'saves state' and doesn't calculate everything at once, rather it calculates with each call to `next`.  How does this work?  For example `[x for x in range(10) if x%2==0]` vs `(x for x in range(10) if x%2==0)`.  In the list comprehension, everything is calculated and stored in memory at once.

In the generator, the entire list is not produced but instead an iterable generator object which calculates with each call to next.  But this generator must somehow know it's "bounds", right?  How does the generator know, if it isn't in the background performing all the calculations, where to pick up where it left off? I would think it has to know each step in the list comprehension and ultimately if you end up cycling through the entire generator until a StopIteration is hit, I would think you are using roughly the same amount of memory.

Comment: Heh, @thefourtheye, I was about to rehash that same info into slightly different form, indeed. But the other answer does indeed hold enough information to answer this question too.

Comment: `range` will return a list (at least in python 2x)... basically completely wiping out any benefit from generators ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: lets charitably assume the OP is using Python 3.x then. :-)

Comment: yeah yeah fair enough :P

Answer (score 1):

> But this generator must somehow know it's "bounds", right?

No it doesn't! It just keeps on trucking until it hits a `StopIteration`. It is only ever handling one element in memory at a time, then discards it.

Comment: I'll review the proposed duplicates above (I did try to search before hand), but this is basically what I'm not understanding.  To only handle one item at a time, it must know where in the order of the iterable object it stands, so how can it know that if it discards each prior element?  In otherwords, how does it know next has already beencalled 'x' many times and that it needs to now perform the calculation the 'third' time, for example if it is not keeping a cumulative tally of calculations (and thus I would think eliminating memory benefit by the time a StopIteration is hit)

Comment: Try giving [this article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) a read. Generators will simply keep calling `next` every time you want an element, until they hit a `StopIteration`. They do not, and can not, know where the `StopIteration` will occur until they get there.

Comment: For future learners... I found section 3.5 of SICP helped me tremendously here.  It won't help you understand python's particular implementation, but the the general concepts are explained very clearly.